# Visual Studio cant find reference once start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, user-controls

i have a problem with my Visual Studio.

I have a Solution with 4 projects(WinForm Application):

1. Client App
2. Server App
3. Shared Library
4. UserControls

The reference for each project:

1 has reference 3 and 4

2 has reference 3

3 has no reference

4 has reference 3

Once i close the Visual Studio and reopen it i receive the following errors:

On the forms that the UserControls in design (the Form is cannot be edited):

> Could not find type 'UserControls.xxx'. Please make sure that the
>   assembly that contains this type is referenced.

On the Error List

> Reference component 'Shared Library' could not be found
>
> Reference component 'UserControl' could not be found

If i Clean and Build again the errors does not disappear.

But if i follow the following steps (in the exact order)

1. Build only Shared Library
2. Build only UserControls
3. Build only Client App
4. Build only Server App (After this step the error in Error List disappears but The error on the form exist. The program can debug with no problem which means you can also open the forms with the UserControls)
5. Close Form in design
6. Open Form in design (The form appears and can be edited)

Could you please help me? i would like to avoid doing all that every time i open Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you checked your OutputPath in VS; does it help to change the OutputPath to `../Binaries_Debug/` (all projects!) for example?

Comment: Did you add the references as DLLs or as Projects?

Comment: @Essigwurst I change the paths to be the same for each project but it does not help

Comment: @ShakSmith they are referenced as Project

Comment: I mean, if you put two dots "../folder" in front of your output dir, vs will put the bin's a level to the top, so if you compile all projects to the same folder, dereferencing and rereferencing the dll's you should be fine..

Comment: Is your project target as 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I would suggest for you to go to the Project Dependencies located in the Solution properties. There you can select the dependencies for each project. Try that and let me know if you still keep having the same issues.

Comment: @Nemanja i tried all combinations .. 32bit ...64bit and Any CPU

Comment: @ShakSmith Unfortunately it does not help. the thing is when i click Clean and the Build Solution. The Build proccess is correct.1>------ Build started: Project: IMS_Shared.Library, Configuration: Debug|AnyCPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: IMS_Shared.xControls.....

Comment: I've had issues similar to that. In some cases, it was because the projects were added as dll's and as projects. If the project dependencies are fine and the project build order is fine, try deleting the .suo file. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: @ShakSmith OMG! Thank you very very much i deleted the .suo file which was recreated after first build and it now works. I can close and open my VB an there is no problem. Thank you again (and all other people who helped) for your time

Comment: I'm glad it worked!